# SQL query GROUP BY colA and ORDER by ColB issue

Tags: sql, ms-access, distinct

What I am trying to do is to do a Distinct on only 1 Column with Access.
Access is unfortunately limited and we have to use an aggregate function.

```
SELECT ColB, max(ColA), Max(ColC)... 
FROM Table1 
WHERE blabalba 
GROUP BY ColB
```

the query is working fine but what I would need is to have the result ORDER BY ColA and I can't if I add ORDER BY ColA at the end, I get the exeption Y*ou tried to execute a query that does not include the specified expression 'CSR' as part of an aggregate function.*

How can we have this query order by ColA?

Also I don't know if this one is possible but I would need for the results to have ColA in the first position so basically we do a kind of a DISTINCT on ColB only and we order by ColA

```
ColA            ColB          ColC
1                A              @
1                A              #
1                B              #
2                C              %
2                D              &
3                E              *
3                E              !
3                E              @
3                F              $
```

Results

```
ColA           ColB            ColC
1               A               @
1               B               #
2               C               %
2               D               &
3               E               *
3               F               $
```

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To order by ColA, could you try this query?

```
SELECT colb, maxcola, maxcolc
FROM (
  SELECT ColB, max(ColA) AS maxcola, Max(ColC) AS maxcolc 
  FROM Table1 
  WHERE blabalba 
  GROUP BY ColB
) AS sub
ORDER BY maxcola;
```

Or, if that doesn't work in Access, could you save the first query as a View and then query from the view using an ORDER BY?